# Calculate simple formula with only one register

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers, micro-optimization

I would like to calculate the following formula very fast and ONLY with EAX:

```
eax = ( eax - 0x01010101 ) AND (NOT eax)
```

Is this possible? What do the assembler specialists think?
I get stuck myself because assembler is not my programming language.

Comment: The most efficient way is going to involve 2 registers, like `lea` to copy-and-subtract, then BMI1 `andn` to to the andnot.  https://godbolt.org/z/vK7s4jczq shows `gcc -m32 -mregparm=3` (so arg arrives in EAX, return value in EAX).  Which is more important to you?  Finding some way to avoid push/pop to save/restore another register around this, or to make it fast?  If this is related to https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#ZeroInWord, are you sure you can't just use SSE2 `pcmpeqb xmm0, xmm1`?

Comment: Without using memory, probably no.  The whole point of doing the `- 0x01...` is that it can produce carry-out, affecting other bits, so the original EAX value is lost if you do that first.  And there isn't an instruction that ANDs an ADD result to restore it on the fly without separate storage.  This might be a more useful question if you posted more about your design constraints to figure out the best alternative.  I'm reluctant to post an answer that just says "no", that doesn't seem useful to future readers.

Comment: @fuz: Compilers aren't going to make it any slower in order to use only 1 register (if that's even possible at all at the cost of more instructions).  Checking compiler output does show us that the fast way they use (which I think is optimal) involves a tmp register.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ah yes, I missed the requirement to only use a single register.

Comment: Is this formula supposed to give a correct result if any of the bytes in `eax` is zero?

Comment: If we really want to just check for a zero byte, then for 7-bit encoding: `(e - 0x01010101) & 0x80808080)`. And for 8-bit (except 0x80, which seem to be false-positive for original formula as well) do a mask prior to computation: `((e & 0x7f7f7f7f) - 0x01010101) & 0x80808080`. It's only good as replacement for zero/non-zero check of course. The numerical result is completely different.